# How to use useEffect/state/variables properly without user interaction?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is to set up a game loop but a simple test isn't working as expected. In the following component, I am trying the `useEffect` hook to increment `food`. I expect to see "Food: 1". Instead I see "Food: 0". When I inspect the component with the dev tools, I can see that food is 2. I've discovered that the component mounts, increments food, unmounts, mounts again and increments food once more.

I have two questions:

1. Can I do something about the double mount? (like prevent it or wait until the final mount with a nested component perhaps?)
2. Why does the displayed food count still equal zero? Is it because `game` inside `<span>Food: {game.food}</span>` still refers to the initial instance? If so, how do I get the latest instance?

Component:

```
import React from "react";

class Game {
  food = 0;
}

export default function App() {
  const [game, setGame] = React.useState(new Game());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setGame((game) => {
      game.food += 1;
      return game;
    });
  });

  return <span>Food: {game.food}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't Mutate State Objects**

React uses reference comparisons and expects the reference of the root state object to change if any data within it has changed.

For Example:

```
// DON'T
setGame((game) => {
    // mutate and return same object
    game.food += 1;
    return game;
});

// DO
setGame((current) => {
    // create new object with updated food value
    return {
        ...current,
        food: current.food + 1
    };
});
```

Using the same reference will cause components to not update as expected.

**useEffect Dependency Array**

A `useEffect` without a dependency array will trigger every time the component renders.

If you wish for the `useEffect` to only trigger on mount provide an empty dependency array.

For Example:

```
// Every Render
useEffect(() => {
    alert('I trigger every render');
});

// On Mount
useEffect(() => {
    alert('I trigger on mount');
}, []);

// Everytime the reference for game changes
useEffect(() => {
    alert('I trigger everytime the game state is update');
}, [game]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about why things aren't working as expected (because the setter is expecting a new object under the hood)!

The detail about using an empty array to only trigger once is also great to know. I feel like I've read the documentation carefully about that second argument but I guess not!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Conclusion

1. "Mount twice" probably you are using react 18 and have strict mode enabled. It will trigger useEffect twice in dev mode [from docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)
2. If you want to update the view, you should make the reference of the game variable changes (instead of changing its attrs).

### Solution

```js
const initialGame = {
  food: 0
}

export default function App() {
  const [game, setGame] = React.useState(initialGame);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setGame((game) => {
      game.food += 1;
      return {...game};
    });
  }, []);

  return <span>Food: {game.food}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0. No you should not useEffect as a loop, its execution depends on your component states and its parent component, so this leaves 3 solutions 1st `while` loop, 2nd [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and 3rd `setInterval`. while loop is discouraged because it will block event loop and canceling/stopping can be tedious.
1. double mount ? i think its react double checking function, which does this only dev mode. Once you switch to `requestAnimationFrame` you won't be having that issue.
2. use tried mutate state and react doesn't recognizes this so it doesn't re render. solution: return new object.

---

updating states

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setGame((current) => {
    const newState = { ...current, food: current.food + 1 }
    return newState
  })
}, [])
```

using `setInterval` to act as loop

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(() => setCount((count) => count + 1), 1000)
  return () => clearInterval(id)
}, [])
```

using `requestAnimationFrame` to act as loop

```js
// credit: https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/
const requestRef = React.useRef()

const animate = (time) => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1)
  requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

useEffect(() => {
  requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current)
}, []) // Make sure the effect runs only once
```